# Directed acyclic graph through removing arches or reverting them

Tags: graph-theory, cycle, directed-acyclic-graphs, equivalence

I have been struggling now with a way to formalize and throughouly prove the following:

We are given the street network of a city. Prove that if we can remove all cycles in this network by creating at most p blockins, then we can remove all the cycles in the city network by reversing one way of at most p streets.

Blocking means obstructing one way of the street. Reversing - (in case of a two-way street) means that one of the ways is inverted and then both ways are the same. Reversing (in case of a one-way street) means that the only way is inverted

Now, the problem translates into having a random directed graph at first, which may have cycles we have to remove. 
Through the BLOCKING method, we are guaranteed that if we block at most p nodes, we will obtain a DAG. So the problem, on short, actually, is to prove that blocking is equivalent in the result and steps (number of edges removed/reversed) made.

For testing the equivalency in the case of a two-way street it is pretty redundant:

for blocking: 
A ---> B, B <--- A
through blocking becomes A ---> B / A <---B and the other one BLOCKED

for reversing, it still becomes A--->B / B---->A, with one of the ways reversed

But what should i do to prove they are equivalent in the case of only one-way streets? I have tried testing in different cycles in directed graphs to see if reverting one arch could create more cycles, when in fact it just keeps the same number or decreases them. But i dont know how to formally prove the equivalency of the two operations.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good question for StackOverflow. If you could present the question in a more mathematical form, it may be suitable at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math rather than about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 0):

This is mathematical (graph theory) question.

Outline of a proof is to map p blockings into p inversions to get same result (removing of all cycles.)

Blocking and inversion on two way street have same effect (makes street one-way.)

Main thing is to show that inversion of one way street will not leave a cycle which is removed by blocking that street. That can be seen by assuming that inversion will leave/create a cycle that is otherwise blocked. That cycle is in opposite direction than cycle that is prevented by blocking same street. So, we have two cycles that meet on one street in opposite directions. These cycles (without the street) can be concatenated into a cycle which doesn't include that street, so block on that street will not remove that cycle. Which is a contradiction that blocking of that street is needed at all.